# How can I check if a NSString is equal with a character at specific index in another NSString?

Tags: objective-c

I tried so far:

```
if ([randomString isEqualToString:[anotherRandomString atIndex:1]]){
    stuff
}
```

which returns this error:

> error: instance method '-atIndex:' not found

and

```
[arg1 isEqualToString:[password2 characterAtIndex:1]]
```

returns this error

> error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSString *' with an rvalue of type 'unichar'

Answer (score 2):

Get the desired substring from `anotherRandomString` and then compare that to `randomString`.

```
NSString *substring = [anotherRandomString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(someIndex, 1)];
if ([randomString isEqualToString:substring]) {
}
```

Comment: If the string was "word" wouldnt that return "wo" if i do `...NSMakeRange(someIndex, 2)];` ? I want only one character

Comment: But I didn't say to pass `2` as the length. I showed that you need to pass `1` as the length.

Comment: @J.Doe You need to clarify with example because it's unclear. From your question is was looking like it was comparing only ONE char (string of length 1). You may want `if ([[anotherRandomString substringFromIndex:1] hasPrefix:randomString]){//stuff}`